# Split a string to be used in the IN Operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query like this:

```
Declare @SuspendedTo varchar(100) = 'Processing,Personal Service'
Select @SuspendedTo
Select top 100 SuspendedTo, *
from #temp_SuspenseResults
where SuspendedTo in (@SuspendedTo)
```

The problem with this query is that the `@SuspendedTo` is regarded as a single string and this doesn't return any results. How do I split the `@SuspendedTo` such that I get the following query:

```
Select top 100 SuspendedTo, *
from #temp_SuspenseResults
where SuspendedTo in ('Processing', 'Personal Service')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `string_split()`:

```
Select top 100 SuspendedTo, sr.*
from #temp_SuspenseResults sr
where sr.SuspendedTo in (select value from string_split(@SuspendedTo, ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Declare @SuspendedTo varchar(100) = 'Processing,Personal Service'

Select @SuspendedTo

Select top 100 SuspendedTo, *
from #temp_SuspenseResults
OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@SuspendedTo,',') s
where SuspendedTo in (s.value)
```

Also we can achieve the Same by using **XML NODES**

```
Declare @SuspendedTo varchar(100) = 'Processing,Personal Service'

DECLARE @SuspendedToXML XML=cast('<r>'+replace(@SuspendedTo, ',', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)

Select top 100 SuspendedTo, *
from #temp_SuspenseResults
INNER JOIN (                    
                   SELECT r.value('.', 'varchar(50)') Location_id                    
                   FROM @SuspendedToXML.nodes('r') AS fn(r)                    
                   ) AS X ON X.Location_id =SuspendedTo
```